# Have TeXstudio look for package and class file in different folder

Tags: packages, texstudio, files

I have a big project, consisting of multiple files, all of which use a package and a class I created. The .tex files can’t be compiled without said package and class. I would like to move the location of some of the .tex files in my PC (to a new folder that is a GitHub repository), however the package and the class wouldn’t be on the same folder as the .tex files, causing an error. Is there any way to “tell” TeXstudio where to look for them? If not, can it be done with another LaTeX editor? I am using Windows and MiKTeX distribution.

Comment: TeXstudio is just an editor; it has little to do with the rest of your TeX setup. What OS and LaTeX distribution are you using?

Comment: @Ingmar Sorry, I didn't know the issue wasn't related to TeXstudio. I edited the post to add I'm using windows and MiKteX.

Comment: In the MikTeX console under settings there your be a Directories setting. You should be able to add the folder with your personal sty and cls files there. See also https://docs.miktex.org/manual/localadditions.html

Comment: @daleif Could you please be more specific describing the process? I added the directory in settings and tried the methods in MiKTeX documentation but the same error (! LaTeX Error: File `fmbnotes.cls' not found.
) keeps popping up.